# End Date always after Start Date?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Related to, but not the same as [How to change end date automatically after changing start date?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101835/change-end-date-automatically-after-changing-start-date)

I'm looking for a method to have Date fields do some sort of validation on the end date. I don't want it to get set to the start date automatically, but I'd like end end date to get bumped forward if they set a start date after the end date.

Alternatively, I'd at least like the datepicker to default to the start date's month when they open the form. Is this just going to be a little javascript module, or does this functionality exist already somewhere I'm missing?

Looking in the date field settings, there's a way to set default start and end dates, but they don't update obviously.

Is the answer just doing a bunch of javascript/jquery login on the fields whenever my users enter data? It seems like this should exist somewhere already.